# Error while compiling the code in Android Studio 0.4.2 [ :app:processDebugResources , resource not found ]

Tags: android-studio

1.No resource found that matches the given name (at 'padding' with value '@dimen/default_gap').

2.Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\bujima\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.0.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\bujima\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\bujima\AndroidStudioProjects\Musicplayer2\app\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\bujima\AndroidStudioProjects\Musicplayer2\app\build\res\all\debug -A C:\Users\bujima\AndroidStudioProjects\Musicplayer2\app\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\bujima\AndroidStudioProjects\Musicplayer2\app\build\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\bujima\AndroidStudioProjects\Musicplayer2\app\build\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package edu.asu.ecs.tel
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       C:\Users\bujima\AndroidStudioProjects\Musicplayer2\app\build\res\all\debug\layout\fragment_setting.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'padding' with value '@dimen/default_gap').

Comment: have you defined the dimension called default_gap in values/dimens.xml ? Your layout fragment_setting.xml is using that.

Comment: <resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="default_gap" />

</resources>

Comment: still showing error as

Comment: add your dimens.xml and ragment_setting.xml in question.

Comment: dimens.xml already posted

Comment: is your problem resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not define any dimensions without value inside it.

This is how your `dimens.xml` should look like

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
      <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
      <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
      <dimen name="default_gap" >your_value_here_in_dp</dimen>

</resources>
```